# Call an array that contains other arrays to a function without having to call each individual array

Tags: javascript

I want to display the result of all numbers multiplied by ten without calling each individual array.

```
const num1 = [2,4, 6, 8,];
const num2 = [12,14, 16, 18,];
const num3 = [22, 24, 26, 28, ];
const num4 = [32, 34, 36, 38, ];
const numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4];

const timesTen = num1.map(num => {
    return num * 8
}
    );
    console.log(`Here are the results ${timesTen}`);
```

Comment: you may want the `flat` array method

Comment: fyi: `return num * 8` and `timesTen` don't correlate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const num1 = [2,4, 6, 8,];
const num2 = [12,14, 16, 18,];
const num3 = [22, 24, 26, 28, ];
const num4 = [32, 34, 36, 38, ];
const numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4];

const timesTen = numbers.reduce((all,cur) => [...all, ...cur]).map(num => {
    return num * 10
});
console.log(`Here are the results ${timesTen}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const num1 = [2,4, 6, 8,];
const num2 = [12,14, 16, 18,];
const num3 = [22, 24, 26, 28, ];
const num4 = [32, 34, 36, 38, ];
const numbers = [...num1, ...num2, ...num3, ...num4];

const timesTen = numbers.map(num => {
    return num * 10
}
    );
    console.log(`Here are the results ${timesTen}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  How does the ... change the array?

Comment: I thought you just wanted to print the timesTen array, what you want to change?

Comment: If i run the code with out the ... in the numbers array, this is the result.         Here are the results NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN                I want to understand what the ... does?

Comment: No, if you are not expanding the array then  numbers is something like this [[2,4,6,8], [12,14,16,18]] but if you are expanding with ... then numbers array will be  like this [2,4,6,8,12,14,...]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax This explains the ... aka spread operator.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it with a string, the result was ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, .  It doesn't work with strings?

Answer (score 0):

Using flat

```js
const num1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, ];
    const num2 = [12, 14, 16, 18, ];
    const num3 = [22, 24, 26, 28, ];
    const num4 = [32, 34, 36, 38, ];
    const numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4];
    
    const aa = numbers.flat();
    
    const flattened = aa.map(el =>{
     return el * 10
    })
    
    console.log(flattened)
```

If you have to repeat the process a lot of times, use a function :

```
const multiply = myArr => {
const theMagic =  myArr.flat().map(el => el * 10)
return theMagic;
}

console.log(multiply(numbers))
```

Comment: flat + map = flatMap ;)